# Adding a custom delay to UVM backdoor access

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I've got two instances of a DUT that run in lockstep, one running *T* cycles later than the other. I know I can add multiple paths using `reg_block.add_hdl_path` for backdoor accesses to both instances. However, I'd like to reflect the actual cycle delay behavior when doing a backdoor write i.e. the second instance gets the new value *T* cycles after the first instance gets it. Is there a way to do it? The only hints I could find were `uvm_reg_backdoor` but I'm not sure that's what will help me.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of backdoor access with zero delay. You'll need to delay issuing the backdoor write command by the number of cycles you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying Dave. What I'm specifically asking is if there's a way to customize `uvm_reg` 's `write` function with backdoor access to do what I want to do, by way of callbacks or such. And as I write this I think I may have just figured out the answer. I could use a `post_write` to trigger a backdoor access to the corresponding register _T_ cycles later, right?

Comment: @ArunD'souza You mean `pre_write()`.

Comment: @TudorTimi I think I mean `post_write()`. If I do it pre-write and the task is blocking, then the callback will execute before the write. The callback will consume _T_ cycles and then write to the second instance of the DUT. After that, the write will commence which basically means we wrote both at the same time, albeit _T_ cycles after the user called write.

Comment: @ArunD'souza The most common idiom regarding delays is to always delay before performing a transaction. E.g., if you want to issue a bus transfer, you wait `delay` cycles and then start driving the transaction. In your case, the backdoor write is your transaction.

Comment: This is not for modelling transaction based delays that go through a sequencer/driver. This is to model a lockstepped network where registers get programmed through the DUT's interface but the shadow network sees this _T_ cycles later. The problem comes when there are transactions in flight during this 0-cycle reprogramming and both sub-DUT instances see different register values leading to diverging behavior. Why there are transactions is not something I want to get into :(